# Spring AMQP/RabbitMQ transaction rollback in EJB3 CMT

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to test the rollback of a transaction that was initiated by EJB3 container, which involves the Spring JPA repository call and the message sender to the RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP integration. After the CMT rollback I see the DB transaction gets rolled back, but the message is getting delivered to the queue.

I am injecting the spring bean into the EJB that makes a call to the Rabbit template and it has @Transactional annotation. What I see is the TransactionInterceptor is committing the transaction after the Spring bean send message call. I was hoping it would delegate the commit to the container.

Any suggestions/workarounds are appreciated. I wasn't able to figure out how to initialize the TransactionSynchronizationManager without using the @Transactional annotation.

Here is the code that is committing the transaction when the spring bean proxy executes the TransactionInterceptor code:

```
ResourceHolderSynchronization
  @Override
  public void afterCommit()
  {
    if (!shouldReleaseBeforeCompletion()){  -- this method returns false
        processResourceAfterCommit(this.resourceHolder);    -- this is calling commitAll
     }
  }

ConnectionFactoryUtils/RabbitResourceSynchronization
        @Override
        protected boolean shouldReleaseBeforeCompletion() {
            return !this.transacted; -- transacted is true (channelTransacted)
}   

RabbitResourceHolder        
public void commitAll() throws AmqpException {
        try {
            for (Channel channel : this.channels) {
                if (deliveryTags.containsKey(channel)) {
                    for (Long deliveryTag : deliveryTags.get(channel)) {
                        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
                    }
                }
                channel.txCommit();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AmqpException("failed to commit RabbitMQ transaction", e);
        }
    }
```

Here is my spring configuration:

```
  <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
  <tx:annotation-driven  />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
    addresses="node01:5672,node02:5672" username="user.." password="pwd..." />


<bean id="rabbitTemplate" 
    class="org.arbfile.monitor.message.broker.api.rabbitmq.CustomRabbitTemplate" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryTemplate" />
    <property name="exchange" value="user.example.exchange" />
    <property name="queue" value="user.example.queue" />
    <property name="routingKey" value="user.example.queue" />
    <property name="channelTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Seems it's only problem with the EJB/CMT integration. If I use the REST layer in front everything works fine. I suspect some kind of spring specific transactional weaving is missing if the client calls EJB3.

Comment: The JIRA issue on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-479.